# Coldfusion - Post to FB feed with message, image, and URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to post to a Facebook feed with a message, image (URL), and a link using CFHTTP. I can't figure out from FB documentation how to do the image and URL. I can post the message just fine but when I try an image and link it doesn't work.

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/#facebookSettingsPageID#/feed" result="facebookResponse" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam name="access_token" type="formfield" value="#facebookPageToken#">
    <cfhttpparam name="message" type="formfield" value="#form.message#">
    <cfhttpparam name="picture" type="FORMFIELD" value="#form.pic#">
    <cfhttpparam name="link" type="FORMFIELD" value="#form.urlLink#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "doesn't work". Error message?

Comment: Or a broken image? If it is broken, is the path what you were expecting?

Comment: You can only specify the image while posting, if you verified link ownership first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/page/feed#custom-image Otherwise the thumbnail will be taken from the OG meta tags of the shared URL.

Comment: I don't get any error messages or anything, I just don't see the post on the FB page if I add in the picture cfhttpparam. If I leave that parameter out, the message will be posted to the FB page. I'm trying to figure out how to do the ownership_permissions{can_customize_link_posts}. Can I do that within  CFHTTP?

Answer (score 0):

"Can you provide us the complete url of the image you're trying to upload.

For domain verification follow the steps provided in the link below.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification"